# Translating a (slightly complex) raw SQL query to ActiveRecord/Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a very simple Rails app with a very simple relational database: Category has many Samples. I'd simply like to load the categories that have X number of samples.

In plain SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT
    categories.*
FROM
    categories
JOIN
    (SELECT
        category_id, COUNT(*) as sample_count
    FROM
        samples
    GROUP BY
        category_id
    ) AS subselect
ON
    categories.id=subselect.category_id
WHERE
    subselect.sample_count = X; -- where X is whatever
```

That works just fine, by the way, but it's not terribly Rails-like to use raw SQL. And obviously I'd like to get those categories as model instances, so:

**How would I go about re-writing something like that to an ActiveRecord or Arel query?** Is it even feasible, or should I go with the plain SQL? Is there perhaps an altogether simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible nice way would be to use counter_cache, as described on this page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Add a column named samples_count to your Category model:

```
add_column :categories, :samples_count, :integer
```

In your Sample model update belongs_to as follows:

```
belongs_to :category , :counter_cache => true
```

You can now use the count as a condition, for example:

```
Category.where(:samples_count => 7)
```

Comment: Ah, very nice and clean! I was thinking about adding a `samples_count` column to categories, but I didn't know Rails had the logic built-in for keeping it up-to-date (don't know how I missed that). Didn't want to write that myself, so I didn't pursue it :)